# Why is it unable to read the PropType.func?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a component ChannelSection.jsx which is not the outermost component, App.jsx will be the outermost component. My ChannelSection will need to receive props from its parent component. So added the prop types bellow:

ChannelSection.jsx:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ChannelForm from './ChannelForm.jsx';
import ChannelList from './ChannelList.jsx';

class ChannelSection extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ChannelList {...this.props} />
                <ChannelForm {...this.props} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ChannelSection.propTypes = {
    channels: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    setChannel: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    addChannel: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default ChannelSection
```

And I am getting this error in the console and I am not sure why and I need some assistance in troubleshooting this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined
```

My App.jsx file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ChannelSection from './channels/ChannelSection.jsx';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            channels: []
        };
    }
    addChannel(name){
        let {channels} = this.state;
        channels.push({id: channels.length, name});
        this.setState({channels});
        // TODO: Send to Server
    }
    setChannel(activeChannel){
        this.setState({activeChannel});
        // TODO: Get Channel Messages
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <ChannelSection  
              channels={this.state.channels} 
              addChannel={this.addChannel.bind(this)}
              setChannel={this.setChannel.bind(this)} />
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Title says PropType did you ensure that nowhere in the app you are using PropType? The snippets you post look right and properly use PropTypes, but is it possible you have PropType somewhere else.

Comment: @kwelch, good call, in ChannelForm.jsx I had some PropTypes that were lower case. Go ahead and post your response as the answer so I can check it off and thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you are using `React.PropTypes` in all cases. It being plural and case both matter.

**Update**

`React.PropTypes` is now deprecated. Please use the `prop-types` `npm` package which has a default export `PropTypes`.

Those using `PropTypes` from the `react` package, you can use `react-codemod` to update your project.